# Solve the error in .getPurchaseDetails and .isPurchased

Tags: android, flutter, dart, in-app-purchase, subscription

## Solve the error in .getPurchaseDetails and .isPurchased

I add in-app-subscription for the app content. When purchase is success or already purchased then then the screen enter's the next page of my app. But i face an problem in .isPurchased and .isPurchased. I need help to fix it and make payment through the android in app subscription.

## Screenshot of the problem

[image: Error]

## pubspec.yaml

```
dependencies:
   flutter:
      sdk: flutter
  in_app_purchase: ^3.1.11
```

## Full code:

````dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sharemedia/Stream/ShowList.dart';
import 'package:sharemedia/advirtisement/banner_ad.dart';
import 'package:sharemedia/screens/top_liked_photo.dart';
import 'package:in_app_purchase/in_app_purchase.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

class NotifiH extends StatefulWidget {
  const NotifiH({super.key});

  @override
  State<NotifiH> createState() => _NotifiHState();
}

class _NotifiHState extends State<NotifiH> {
  final InAppPurchase _inAppPurchase = InAppPurchase.instance;
  bool _isPurchased = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _initialize();
  }

  void _initialize() async {
    // Check if the user has already purchased the subscription
    final bool isPurchased = await _inAppPurchase.isPurchased('product_id');
    // final bool isPurchased = await _inAppPurchase.buyNonConsumable(purchaseParam: 'product_id')
    setState(() {
      _isPurchased = isPurchased;
    });
  }

  void _buyShareStreamInn() async {
    // Purchase the Share Stream Inn subscription
    final PurchaseParam purchaseParam = PurchaseParam(productDetails: _inAppPurchase.getPurchaseDetails('product_id'));
    await _inAppPurchase.buyConsumable(purchaseParam: purchaseParam);

    // Update the state to reflect the purchase
    setState(() {
      _isPurchased = true;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Container(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              GestureDetector(
                child: Container(
                  height: 42,
                  // width: 90,
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  // margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(
                      width: 3,
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                  ),
                  child: Text(
                    'Show top liked photos',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 14,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                      color: Colors.green,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.of(context).push(
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) => TopLikes(),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              BannerAD(),

              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              GestureDetector(
                child: Container(
                  height: 42,
                  // width: 90,
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  // margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(
                      width: 3,
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                  ),
                  child: Text(
                    'Share Stream',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 14,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                      color: Colors.green,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                onTap: () {
                  if (_isPurchased) {
                    // User has purchased the subscription, allow access to Share Stream
                    Navigator.of(context).push(
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => ShowList(),
                      ),
                    );
                  } else {
                    // User has not purchased the subscription, show purchase dialog
                    showDialog(
                      context: context,
                      builder: (BuildContext context) {
                        return AlertDialog(
                          title: Text('Purchase Share Stream Inn'),
                          content: Text('Do you want to purchase Share Stream Inn?'),
                          actions: [
                            TextButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                              },
                              child: Text('Cancel'),
                            ),
                            TextButton(
                              onPressed: () {
                                _buyShareStreamInn();
                                Navigator.of(context).pop();
                              },
                              child: Text('Purchase'),
                            ),
                          ],
                        );
                      },
                    );
                  }
                },
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              BannerAD(),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              GestureDetector(
                child: Container(
                  height: 42,
                  // width: 90,
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  // margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(
                      width: 3,
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                  ),
                  child: Text(
                    'Meme MEDIA',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 14,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                      color: Colors.green,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                onTap: () async {
                  const url =
                      "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=meme_media.mrkcreations.mskp.com.meme_media";
                  final Uri _url = Uri.parse(url);
                  await launchUrl(
                    _url,
                    mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication,
                  );
                },
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              BannerAD(),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              GestureDetector(
                child: Container(
                  height: 42,
                  // width: 90,
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  // margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(
                      width: 3,
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                  ),
                  child: Text(
                    'V-Share',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 14,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                      color: Colors.green,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                onTap: () async {
                  const url =
                      "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=vshare.mkrcreation.com";
                  final Uri _url = Uri.parse(url);
                  await launchUrl(
                    _url,
                    mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication,
                  );
                },
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              BannerAD(),

              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              GestureDetector(
                child: Container(
                  height: 42,
                  // width: 90,
                  alignment: Alignment.center,
                  // margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(
                      width: 3,
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
                  ),
                  child: Text(
                    'New version of ShareMedia is now available',
                    style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 14,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.w600,
                      color: Colors.green,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
                onTap: () async {
                  const url =
                      "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mskp.tamilanproject.sharemediapro.xyz";
                  final Uri _url = Uri.parse(url);
                  await launchUrl(
                    _url,
                    mode: LaunchMode.externalApplication,
                  );
                },
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              BannerAD(),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}```
````